# i get error thrown when i run this code

Tags: c#

i get this error when ever i try to compile my code here is the error

> Error  1   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

below is my code

```
private void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmFaultyDeviceByPeriod.FirstDate = dateTimePicker1.Value;
    frmFaultyDeviceByPeriod.SeconDate = dateTimePicker2.Value;
    frmFaultyDeviceByPeriod.Show();
}
```

the form am trying to call has the below code

```
public System.DateTime FirstDate;
public System.DateTime SecondDate;
```

what am i doing wrong.. help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, well, `FirstDate` and `SecondDate` are instance members, so you need to set them using an object, not a class.

The error would be more evident if you adhered to the coding style guidelines, starting class names in capital letter.

The way to do it is this:

```
frmFaultyDeviceByPeriod frm = new frmFaultyDeviceByPeriod();
frm.FirstDate = dateTimePicker1.Value;
frm.SeconDate = dateTimePicker2.Value;
frm.Show();
```

Comment: the form opened and closed when i use the using statement; what should i use in this case?

Comment: Remove the `using`. It only makes sense with `ShowDialog`. I'm going to fix my answer.